# How get scale and position parameter for pircture from XSLFPictureShape in pptx?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I use the library Apache POI to parse .PPTX files to their constituents - the text, tables, images and so on. In working with this tool I constantly confronted with the fact that I can not get complete information about the elements of slide. From XSLFPictureShape can I get information about the picture properties that is placed in the conteiner(such as offset, scale, crop etc) - not only get the type of data and file? And I everytime get original pictures even it was croped, scaled and other efects that was aplied to it - that is why I asked for parameters upper.

[image]